# $(U_j)_{j\subset J-\{\infty\}}$ mean? Compactness of a subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d_x)$ be a metric space.$K$ is a compact of $X$. If F is closed in $K$ it implies $F$ is compact.

**Proof:** Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be a covering of $F$ by open sets of $X$. Let $\infty$ be a symbol that is not in $I$, $I´=I\cup\{\infty\}$ and $U_{\infty}=X-F$. So, $(U_i)_{i\in I´}$ is a covering of $K$ by open sets of $X$. As $K$ is a compact it means there is a finite sub-covering that contains $K$, $(U_j)_{j\subset J}$. Therefore $(U_j)_{j\subset J-\{\infty\}}$ is a sub-covering of $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of open sets of $X$ whose union covers $F$

**Questions:**

**1)** What does $(U_j)_{j\subset J-\{\infty\}}$ mean? Is not the following true? $(U_j)_{j\subset J}= (U_j)_{j\subset J-\{\infty\}}$ ?

**2)** How was $F$ proven closed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There is a typo, it should be $j \in J$ of course instead of $j \subset J$. The sub-covering is $$ (U_j)_{j\in (J-\{\infty\})} $$

2) $F$ being closed in $K$ means that there is a closed subset $F' \subset X$ such that $F = K\cap F'$, see [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). But $K$ is also closed and intersections of closed sets are closed, so $F$ is closed too.

Remark: You can show that compact subsets $K$ are closed using the fact that all metric spaces are [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space).